# sorting a list of data frame on a condition

Tags: r

I have a list of data frames containing different number of columns.

Say Y is a list of 3 data frames containing 4,10 and 5 columns respectively

I want to sort these data frames in a list based on a condition that which column will be sorted first and so on. for that i have another list:

```
i1 = list(c(0),c(4,5,2,3),c(3))
i2 = c(0,4,1)
```

in first data frame i don't want to sort anything and for second and third data frame i want to follow the order given in i1 and i2

i have tried writing this function which works for 1 data frame but not working for a list

```
for (i in 1:length(i1){
if (i2[i] < 1) {
  sorted[[i]]=y[[i]]
} else {
  for(j in i1[[i]]){
    sorted[[i]] <- y[[i]][order(y[[i]][j],]
  }}}
```

Comment: i2 is about number of columns to be sorted

Comment: like in first data frame 0 columns will be sorted, 2nd 4 and 3rd 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `Map`

```
Map(function(x,y, z) if(z < 1) x else x[do.call(order, x[y]),], Y, i1, i2)
#[[1]]
#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  3 10  7 10
#2  3  3  4  2
#3  8  8  7  1
#4  6  9  7  6
#5  7  3  4  2

#[[2]]
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
#1  1  7  4  3  5  1  5 10  5   4
#3  8  6  4  7  3  4  5  3  3  10
#4  2  7  2  7  3  3  8  2  2   8
#2  6  1  3  8  4  4  9  5  3  10
#5  3  1 10 10  1  4  6  2  8   5

#[[3]]
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5
#2  3  6  2  3  8
#4 10  1  3  4  2
#5  7  8  4  9  5
#1  2  4  6  4  4
#3  1  9  6  9 10
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
Y <- list(as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 4*5, replace=TRUE), 5, 4)),
 as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 10*5, replace=TRUE), 5, 10)),
 as.data.frame(matrix(sample(1:10, 5*5, replace=TRUE), 5, 5)))
```

Comment: it is not working with lists
saying undefined column selected

Comment: @RahulVij  I created an example based on your descripiton in the data.  It is working for me.  If not, you have to update your post with a reproducible example

Comment: i need to return a list of 3 data frames as output

Comment: @RahulVij  It is returning a `list` of 3 data.frames.  Please check the code using the data I showed

Comment: @RahulVij Regarding your error, I think it could be that the index in 'i1' is not there in the `data.frame` you have